# WPF ListView UI get newly added UI element

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listviewitem

In my application, the user can add, remove and edit elements in a ListView dynamically. It's data is bound to a collection containing objects of a custom class (which properties are bound to the ListView's GridView-Headers to display the the data).

Now I need to find a way to get the ListViewItem UI element object of each newly added or edited item to style the ListViewItem dynamically in the code behind based on certain factors.

Along the way I use the following code, which works fine if the element (both UI element and it's associated data element) have already been added, so in case an element is updated:

```
var listItem = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem;
if (!isValid)
{
    listItem.Background = Brushes.Red;
    listItem.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
}
```

`item` in this case is an object of my custom class that is also found in the ListView's ItemsSource. Events on both ListView.ItemsSource and the collection itself are raised obviously directly after elements have been added, but the UI has not yet been updated, e.g. there's no ListViewItem object yet that corresponds to the newly addded data element, so the method shown above always returns `null` for `listItem`. 
`listView.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged`-event looks promising, but `ItemsChangedEventArgs` doesn't seem to contain any useful information, so I'm really stuck.

While it seems very easy to get to the lists data itself, I haven't found a way to get the UI elements right after they have been created and visually added to the list. The method shown above, only covers updating already exisiting elements.

Comment: Have you considered using a datatrigger in the itemcontainerstyle and or itemtemplate? That would obviate any issues due to recycling containers.

Comment: As I understand it, container recycling is optional and not enabled by default, but correct me if I'm wrong. In my case, the list will never be really big, so I don't see the need for optimization using container recycling, therefore the issue is already being avoided. If I'm missing the point though, please do enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I haven't found a way to get the UI elements right after they have been created and visually added to the list

You could do this by hooking an event handler to the containers in your XAML markup:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="ListViewItem_Loaded" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</ListView>
```

---

```
private void ListViewItem_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = (ListViewItem)sender;
    ...
}
```

Beware that containers may be recycled: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/optimizing-performance-controls#container-recycling